# Need help in using Analytical function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
 sELECT id, pid,
            case WHEN listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)= '' THEN 'null'
             ELSE listagg(distinct apn_nbr,',') within group(order by apn_nbr) 
             END as apn_nbr
                 FROM  (SELECT max(f1.pid) as pid,f1.id,apn_nbr,date
                         FROM table_1 f1
                         JOIN table_2 d1
                         ON f1.process_id = d1.process_id
                         WHERE apn_nbr is not null 
                         and id=1234576
                         // AND pid='5812900'
                 GROUP BY id,apn_nbr)
             group by id,pid
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting results like what is it mentioned below:

```
ID            PID              APN_NBR
220247111   64306012133      228887143,130050106,220247111,220247143
220247111   57558164496      105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609
```

For one ID, I'm getting different values for PID and APN_NBR column. I need the last NOT NULL records to be displayed in the result.

When I try to use
`QUALIFY rank() over (partition by ID, pid order by datedesc) = 1`, I'm not getting the listagg values as comma separated. I'm getting only one record(i.e. the first record for APN_NBR column)

Can anyone guide me on this logic?

Thanks in advance :)

Sample Records:

```
ID           PID                                                APN_NBR
30247521    5533433057558       130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788
30247521    5533433059643       105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915
34690213    1594308114486       960513957,970020828
34690213    5943081144866
```

I want to display only one row for each orders. i.e. I want to display the second row for each orders.

Comment: Please share with us sample data and the desired results

Comment: Hi Felipe, I just added few sample records. I want to display only one row for each order. Kindly guide me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried using LAG.

Comment: Not yet Pankaj. I will try that.. But I'm not sure if LAG will work as I need to display only one row for each order. I have 1000s of orders and 1 order contains multiple rows and I need to display only one row for each order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this helps -

Data-set used -

```
select column1,column2,column3 from
values
(30247521,5533433057558,'130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788'),
(30247521,5533433059643,'105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,97
0010915'),
(34690213,1594308114486,'960513957,970020828'),
(34690213,5943081144866,NULL);
+----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  COLUMN1 |       COLUMN2 | COLUMN3                                                                                   |
|----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 30247521 | 5533433057558 | 130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788                     |
| 30247521 | 5533433059643 | 105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915 |
| 34690213 | 1594308114486 | 960513957,970020828                                                                       |
| 34690213 | 5943081144866 | NULL                                                                                      |
+----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query to get result -

```
select column1,column2,nvl2(column3, column3,lag(column3) over (order by column1))
as column3 from
values
(30247521,5533433057558,'130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788'),
(30247521,5533433059643,'105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,97
0010915'),
(34690213,1594308114486,'960513957,970020828'),
(34690213,5943081144866,NULL) ;
+----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  COLUMN1 |       COLUMN2 | COLUMN3                                                                                   |
|----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 30247521 | 5533433057558 | 130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788                     |
| 30247521 | 5533433059643 | 105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915 |
| 34690213 | 1594308114486 | 960513957,970020828                                                                       |
| 34690213 | 5943081144866 | 960513957,970020828                                                                       |
+----------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It is not giving the correct results Pankaj. Thanks for checking this.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have the data in your last table.

```
select ID, PID, APN_NBR
from values
    (30247521, 5533433057558, '130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788'),
    (30247521, 5533433059643, '105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915'),
    (34690213, 1594308114486, '960513957,970020828'),
    (34690213, 5943081144866, NULL)
    t(ID, PID, APN_NBR);
```

| ID | PID | APN_NBR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30247521 | 5533433057558 | 130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788 |
| 30247521 | 5533433059643 | 105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915 |
| 34690213 | 1594308114486 | 960513957,970020828 |
| 34690213 | 5943081144866 | null |

and you want all the rows with `APN_NBR` that are NULL removed, then eliminate them with a WHERE clause:

```
select ID, PID, APN_NBR
from values
    (30247521, 5533433057558, '130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788'),
    (30247521, 5533433059643, '105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915'),
    (34690213, 1594308114486, '960513957,970020828'),
    (34690213, 5943081144866, NULL)
    t(ID, PID, APN_NBR)
WHERE APN_NBR IS NOT NULL;
```

gives:

| ID | PID | APN_NBR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30247521 | 5533433057558 | 130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788 |
| 30247521 | 5533433059643 | 105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915 |
| 34690213 | 1594308114486 | 960513957,970020828 |

Now these result, can be pruned to the only one result per `ID` with preferred order being given to the larger `PID` via a QUALIFY which runs after the WHERE clause has run. You should use ROW_NUMBER here instead of RANK, although I said you can use RANK, because RANK can have 2 firsts (which maybe you do want) if the rows are equal. But on the other hand ROW_NUMBER will silent choose 1 row, which might be different from execution to execution.

```
select ID, PID, APN_NBR
from values
    (30247521, 5533433057558, '130050044,130050106,195050142,960109430,960228707,960542787,960542788'),
    (30247521, 5533433059643, '105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915'),
    (34690213, 1594308114486, '960513957,970020828'),
    (34690213, 5943081144866, NULL)
    t(ID, PID, APN_NBR)
WHERE APN_NBR IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by ID order by PID desc) = 1;
```

| ID | PID | APN_NBR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34690213 | 1594308114486 | 960513957,970020828 |
| 30247521 | 5533433059643 | 105450046,105450314,136010476,136150077,184060007,186930609,196051036,960113678,970010915 |

Now these might be the exactly results you want, but this is how to use WHERE and QUALIFY/ROW_NUMBER to filter and order and restrict the results shown. And if you experiment with small toy datasets, like the above provided, and internalize how this functions work. You should be able to apply them to the data you do have, and the transformations you want to apply.

Given you have a grouping in the outer SELECT you can using HAVING to apply a post GROUPING filter, like so:

```
sELECT id, pid,
            case WHEN listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)= '' THEN 'null'
             ELSE listagg(distinct apn_nbr,',') within group(order by apn_nbr) 
             END as apn_nbr
                 FROM  (SELECT max(f1.pid) as pid,f1.id,apn_nbr,date
                         FROM table_1 f1
                         JOIN table_2 d1
                         ON f1.process_id = d1.process_id
                         WHERE apn_nbr is not null 
                         and id=1234576
                         // AND pid='5812900'
                 GROUP BY id,apn_nbr)
             group by id,pid
HAVING APN_NBR IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by ID order by PID desc) = 1;
```

OR you could just add another layer of selects to apply the pattern shown:

```
SELECT id,pid,apn_nbr FROM(sELECT id, pid,
case WHEN listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') 
within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)= '' THEN 'null'
ELSE listagg(distinct apn_nbr,',') within 
group(order by apn_nbr) END as apn_nbr
FROM(SELECT max(f1.pid) as pid,f1.id,apn_nbr,
date FROM table_1 f1 JOIN table_2 d1 ON 
f1.process_id = d1.process_id WHERE 
apn_nbr is not null and id=1234576
// AND pid='5812900'
GROUP BY id,apn_nbr) group by id,pid)
WHERE APN_NBR IS NOT NULL QUALIFY 
row_number() over (partition by ID order 
by PID desc) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Simeon:) I tried the qualify row_number inside the inner query and so it was not working for me.

Comment: I see, that would be disappointing. Can I ask why you put it in the inner query, if the results at the outer level match the "fake data" shown in the example? Can I also ask if you have played with the commands insolation, so are learn how they work? Because if you learn how the parts work, putting them together is trivial, when you understand the tools, and the data, and the problem you are trying to answer.